# Google Analytics Tracking for 1 page to another

Tags: events, google-analytics, event-tracking

I want to track how many users proceed from a website portfolio page to the product detail page. How can we track this event? What are the tracking parameters I need to set up (category, action, label) which can be used by the developers

Comment: You could just use the navigation summary in the Behavior/Site Content/All Pages report (select the page you want to inspect and click the navigaton summary tab above the report pane, it will give you previous and next page for your url).

Answer (score 0):

You can get that value just tracking pageview. You have to use a segment based on sequences to isolate users that visited portfolio page followed by product detail page. Even if you use events the concept is the same.